Window not defined Nextjs error while deployment
I'm trying to deploy my app for a while and in my both of my pages im getting the error of "no window defined" the routes is src->app->flashcards->page.tsx and src->app->collection->page.tsx. Ive moved all the necessary code in useEffect and added 'use client' to both of the components but still not working.
FlashCard Component:

    export default function FlashcardComponent() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState<Flashcard[]>([]);
  const [saveStatus, setSaveStatus] = useState("Save");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { isLoaded, userId } = useAuth(); // Ensure auth is loaded  


  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleGenerate = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/FlashCards', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ content: input }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${response.statusText}`);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      setFlashcards(data.flashcards);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating flashcards:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSave = async () => {
    if (!userId) {
      console.error('User is not authenticated');
      return;
    }

    const stackName = prompt("Enter a name for your stack of flashcards:");
    if (!stackName) {
      console.error('No name provided for the stack');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const stackRef = doc(db, `users/${userId}/flashcardsStacks/${stackName}`);
      await setDoc(stackRef, { name: stackName, flashcards });
      console.log('Flashcards stack saved successfully');
      setSaveStatus("Saved!");

      setTimeout(() => setSaveStatus("Save"), 1000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving flashcards:', error);
    }
  };

  return (/*rest of the code*/)};

and this is my collectionPage:
  const [flashcardStacks, setFlashcardStacks] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { isLoaded, userId } = useAuth(); // Ensure auth is loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && userId && isLoaded) {
      const fetchFlashcardStacks = async () => {
        try {
          const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
            collection(db, 'users', userId, 'flashcardsStacks')
          );
          const stacks = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }));
          setFlashcardStacks(stacks);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching flashcard stacks:', error);
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };

      fetchFlashcardStacks();
    }
  }, [userId, isLoaded]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-screen bg-zinc-950 text-white">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (/*rest of the code*/)}


The window object should definitely be defined there. My intuition says this is some sort of IDE bug, or something funny is going on like you redefined or imported window somewhere else in your code.
